# Tesseracts handles similar Pictures completely different

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract, image-preprocessing

I was just playing around a little with Tesseract as I noticed some strange behavior of the program, which I can’t explain myself. Firstly I gave tesseract this preprocessed Picture1 but it didn’t understand any letter.

[image: Picture1]

Then I put this one in and guess what it gave me?

[image: Picture2]

> Neuinitialisierung des automatischen
>   Karten-Updates erforderlich. Aktuellste

The exact letters and words, every single letter was correct!
So can anybody tell me why it didn't got the text in the first picture.
(btw. I preprocessed the two pictures in the absolut same way)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It **might** have gotten confused by the `ß`. Have you tried putting a white rectangle over it, or replacing it with double "s" to see whether the programme does anything differently?

Comment: good idea! I tried that out and it get's the word! Any Idea how I could overcome that problem?

Comment: Were you using deu.traineddata?

Comment: I just use -lang deu in my script but I was wondering why tesseract didn't stated the other letters "schlie" & "en" if ß is the only Problem. I already tried some other "schließen" pictures where tesseract just missspelled it as "schlief3en".